# Is it possible to use Resource Template Manager in Azure with cloud services

Tags: azure

It looks that the list of services I can deploy with resource template manager for Azure is limited. I see examples for VM, Web Sites, Storage, SQL, but not Cloud Services.

Does anyone know if I can use it for Cloud services (web roles, worker roles)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been mentioned on the User Voice forum for Resource Manager **[HERE](http://feedback.azure.com/forums/281804-azure-resource-manager/suggestions/7899432-add-cloud-services-as-an-available-resource-when-w)**.

It has recently been updated to be a **"planned"** feature as of June 25th. Feel free to add your votes to the feature request!